# XAMPP php file_get_contents takes exactly 30s?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, file-get-contents

So installed XAMPP and have a php file that requests some content with
*file_get_contents($url)*
For some reason this call takes exactly 30 seconds. If I do 2 calls after each other, the php execution time is at least 60 seconds.
However, the request is successful and gets the content from the URL! It just takes those whole 30s.
What can i do about that? Is that a coding mistake or configuration error with XAMPP?

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
echo file_get_contents("https://google.de");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```

results in

> [google page] Total Execution Time: 0.70655170281728 Mins

my network works fine, in the browser i can access the site nearly instantly

Comment: Does it take 30 seconds no matter what you try to retrieve with `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Create a sample file with only `echo 'test';`. Call this file through `file_get_contents` and see if it takes same time.

Comment: Same for any url. Test code attached to question

Comment: verify your domain name resolving settings on that server.

Comment: The apache settings are default from xampp.... what shall i check an where`?

Comment: Have you tried non-secure sites? For example, what about `http://example.com/`?

Comment: Seems that non-secure sites do not take that long. For example neverssl.com took less than a second! Why is that?